# Evaluate $\int \dfrac{dx}{(1+x)\sqrt{1+2x-x^2}}$

Tags: integration

> $$\int \dfrac{dx}{(1+x)\sqrt{1+2x-x^2}}$$

I completed the square:

$\int \dfrac{dx}{(1+x)\sqrt{2-(x-1)^2}}$

And then substituted $\sqrt 2\sin θ = x-1$ which gives

$\int \dfrac{dθ}{\sqrt2 \sinθ + 2}$

But now I'm stuck. Can someone please help?

Comment: Hint: try the Weierstrass substitution $u=\tan(\frac{x}{2})$

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjNp7PPzMH4AhWV1zgGHQHQBn0QFnoECAcQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FWeierstrass_substitution&usg=AOvVaw2NLQZ1A3rMuyXaSY7CRiq2

Comment: Thanks I got it.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a rational function involving trigonometric functions, try a Weierstrass substitution.

$$t=\tan\left(\frac {\theta}2\right)\qquad\mathrm d\theta=\frac {2}{1+t^2}\,\mathrm dt\qquad\sin\theta=\frac {2t}{1+t^2}$$

Hence

$$\begin{align*}\int\frac {\mathrm d\theta}{2+\sqrt{2}\sin\theta} & =\int\frac {\mathrm dt}{t^2+t\sqrt{2}+1}\\ & =\int\frac {\mathrm dt}{\left(t+\frac 1{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2+\frac 12}\end{align*}$$

Can you complete the rest?

---

### Another Approach

I also want to bring to light another possible substitution that, as far as I'm aware, isn't normally taught in a school setting (at least I didn't get taught this).

If you're daring enough and complacent with a large amount of algebraic manipulation up-front, then another possible solution would be to enforce an Euler Substitution of the Second Kind.

The substitution states that for an integral whose integrand is a purely rational function (i.e., no trigonometric terms)

$$\int R\left(x, \sqrt{ax^2+bx+c}\right)\,\mathrm dx$$

Where we impose the condition $c>0$, then an Euler substitution of the Second Kind gives

$$\sqrt{ax^2+bx+c}=xt+\sqrt{c}\qquad\qquad x=\frac {2t\sqrt{c}-b}{a-t^2}$$

In this case, since we have $c>0$, then our substitution is simply

$$\sqrt{1+2x-x^2}=xt+1\qquad\qquad x=\frac {2(1-t)}{1+t^2}$$

With this given substitution for $x$, we have that

$$x+1=\frac {3-2t+t^2}{1+t^2}\qquad\sqrt{1+2x-x^2}=\frac {1+2t-t^2}{1+t^2}\qquad\mathrm dx=\frac {2(t^2-2t-1)}{(1+t^2)^2}\,\mathrm dt$$

Right from the get-go, we can see that a lot of terms will cancel, which is the impressive nature of Euler Substitutions

$$\begin{align*}\int\frac {\mathrm dx}{(1+x)\sqrt{1+2x-x^2}} & =-2\int\frac {1+2t-t^2}{(1+t^2)^2}\frac {1+t^2}{t^2-2t+3}\frac {1+t^2}{1+2t-t^2}\,\mathrm dt\\ & =-2\int\frac {\mathrm dt}{(t-1)^2+2}\\ & =\sqrt{2}\arctan\left(\frac {1-t}{\sqrt2}\right)+C\end{align*}$$

Substituting our expression back in, then we get an impressive result

$$\int\frac {\mathrm dx}{(1+x)\sqrt{1+2x-x^2}}=\sqrt{2}\arctan\left(\frac {1+x-\sqrt{1+2x-x^2}}{x\sqrt2}\right)+C$$

*Confirmed by [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=D%5BSqrt%5B2%5D%20ArcTan%5B%281%20%2B%20x%20-%20Sqrt%5B1%20%2B%202%20x%20-%20x%5E2%5D%29%2F%28x%20Sqrt%5B2%5D%29%5D%2C%20x%5D)*

Answer (score 2):

Another method: Start with $x=\dfrac 1t$ so $dx=\dfrac{-1}{t^2}dt$. We have \begin{align}\int \dfrac{dx}{(1+x)\sqrt{1+2x-x^2}}&= \int \dfrac{\frac{-dt}{t^2}}{\left(1+\dfrac 1t\right)\sqrt{1+\dfrac2t-\dfrac {1}{t^2}}}\\&= \int \dfrac{-dt}{(1+t)\sqrt{t^2+2t-1}}.\end{align} Now use $t+1=u$ so $dt=du$.
$$\int \frac{-du}{u\sqrt{u^2-2}}$$ which can be solved by putting $u^2-2=p$.

---

EDIT: Another, maybe more useful, substitution would be $x+1=v$.

Comment: According to your substitution in front of the square root you need to write 1/t  , you have mistakenly taken it as 1 + 1/t .

Comment: @JanakaRodrigo I have changed something else. I hope it’s fine.

Comment: @insipintegrator I think your earlier substitution is much better because if you do it correctly you may not need another substitution.

Comment: Yes, but the edit was smaller XD I wrote one substitution and performed another substitution *facepalm*. I edited the post.

Answer (score 1):

You may continue with $\theta=\frac\pi2+t$

\begin{align}\int \frac{1}{\sqrt2 \sin\theta+ 2}d\theta
= &\int \frac{1}{\sqrt2 \cos t+ 2}dt= \int \frac{1}{2\sqrt2 \cos^2\frac t2+ 2-\sqrt2}dt\\
=&\int \frac{2d(\tan\frac t2)}{(2-\sqrt2)\tan^2\frac t2+(2+\sqrt2)}=\sqrt2\tan^{-1}\frac{\tan\frac t2}{\sqrt2+1}+C
\end{align}
Or, simply integrate as follows
$$\int \frac{dx}{(1+x)\sqrt{1+2x-x^2}}
= \int \frac{d(\frac{x}{1+x})}{\sqrt{1-2(\frac{x}{1+x})^2}}= \frac1{\sqrt2}\sin^{-1} \frac{\sqrt2x}{1+x}+C
$$

Comment: Nice! I tried using $\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta=1$ with the $\sin\theta$ term and got an integrand with $\sec\theta$ - completely forgot about the double angle identity :P